# Your session crashed for an unknown reason - Google Colab

Tags: python, android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

When i am trying to compile and train the model getting error like : Your session crashed for an unknown reason and restart google colab.

reference link : https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/tensorflow-lite-on-android-2f57267f7297

help me to resolve.

- Compile and Train the model

````
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
loss='categorical_crossentropy',
metrics=['accuracy'])
ep = 25
steps_per_epoch = numpy.asarray(train_generator.n / batch_size)
validation_steps = numpy.asarray(validation_generator.n / batch_size)
history = model.fit(train_generator,
steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
epochs=ep,
validation_data=validation_generator,
validation_steps=validation_steps)```
````